# Can anyone help me with this CPLEX Model?

Tags: c, recursion, optimization, boolean, cplex

I'm trying to sum the stocks cost at each part[i][j] of a tree depending on :

```
X={x[i][j]} 
x[i][j] = 1 if has stock at ij
x[i][j] = 0 if has no stock at
```

The stocks depending on the preparation times, that them selfes depend on if there's any stock before as follow :

```
a[i][j] = t[i][j] if it's the end node
    = t[i][j] + max(s€sons of the brunch){ a[i+1][s] * (1 - x[i][s]}
```

Well the code compiles without any structure errors but the arrays a and the decision variable don't get any response

```
//getting all the sons

range L=0..ligne;
range C=1..colone;

int sons[L][C][C];
int a[L][L];
execute
{
    for (var i in Li){
        for (var j in C){
            for (var k in C){
                if (parent[i+1][k] == j){
                   sons[i][j][k] = k;
                }else
                   sons[i][j][k] = 0;
            }
        }
        a[i][0]=0;
    }
    for (var j in C){
        for (var k in C)
            sons[ligne][j][k]=0;    
    }
 }

//the variable and the objective function and constraints
 dvar boolean x[L][Ci];
  
 dexpr float TotalCost = aih_cost*adup*(1.5+var_factor)*lt_factor*sum(i in L,j   in C)( unit_price[i][j]*rqtf[i][j]*x[i][j]*a[i][j] ); 
 
 minimize TotalCost;
 
 subject to {
    forall(i in Li){
        forall(j in C){     
            forall(k in C) 
            (1-x[i+1][sons[i][j][k]]) * a[i+1][sons[i][j][k]] + t_process[i][j] - a[i][j] >= 0;
        }
}        
    a[0][1]<=service_t; 
}
```

I expect to have at least a proposed array for x, and some preparation times "a".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cplex by default use the solver cplex for linear problems and MILPs.
For my problem, the dependency between "a" and "x" gives it quadratic dimention.

To solve this kind of problems it's needed to use the CP optimizer [cpo](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.studio.help/pdf/usrcpoptimizer.pdf), which is often used for constraints programming but it also gives solution for non linear problems.

Or in an other attempt, i linearized the problem introduction a new decision variable y=a*x and i added a ton of constraints to the model.

Answer (score 2):

Your model may be infeasible.
You could add names to the constraints by turning

```
   forall(i in Li){
        forall(j in C){     
            forall(k in C) 
            (1-x[i+1][sons[i][j][k]]) * a[i+1][sons[i][j][k]] + t_process[i][j] - a[i][j] >= 0;
        }
}        
    a[0][1]<=service_t;
```

into

```
forall(i in Li){
        forall(j in C){     
            forall(k in C) 
            ct1:(1-x[i+1][sons[i][j][k]]) * a[i+1][sons[i][j][k]] + t_process[i][j] - a[i][j] >= 0;
        }
}        
    ct2:a[0][1]<=service_t;
```

and then you could get some relaxation and that could help you.